# Avoiding repeaters in radio-communication

Tags: encryption, authentication, man-in-the-middle, wireless

Suppose a sender and a receiver communicate over some radio channel. Is there a way to prevent packets sent and received are not being repeated/forwarded by a MiTM? That is, when the agents are out of range and the packets are supposed to be lost, no MiTM may effectively repeat those packets.

I've thought about packet timing, but the hardware is low end so the clocks could be inaccurate. I've also thought about DH key exchange and encryption, but the MiTM could still blindly forward whatever encrypted packets captured.

I guess an analogy is GPS. If packets from an arbitrary satellite are repeated, triangulation won't be meaningful.

So, is there any way to stop packet repetition?

**Edit**

The application is indoor navigation using sensor beacons for a robot to navigate around the space. These devices use low end hardware so the clocks may not be accurate, but many sensors are used rather than 3 as in the traditional triangulation. The threat of forwarding packets from unreachable beacons could confuse the robot about its location.

Comment: As stated this seems a straight network question. Perhaps if you told us the problem you are trying to solve we could help you.

Comment: Sure. The application is indoor navigation using sensor beacons for a robot to navigate around the space. These devices use low end hardware so the clocks may not be accurate, but many sensors are used rather than 3 as in the traditional triangulation. The threat of forwarding packets from unreachable beacons could confuse the robot about its location.

Comment: Does authentication + TLS not solve this?

Comment: @SilverlightFox - it does not. The question is not about a standard MiTM attack. The technology in use depends on triangulation based on radio transmitters that are in range. You could set up a repeater that blindly repeats packets even if they are encrypted and unintelligible to the repeater. This would mess up the robot as it would think that it is within range of some radio transmitters when it really isn't.

Comment: @Kar - traditional infosec techniques of encryption and such will not help in the situation you have presented. I'm not actually sure it is solvable. Perhaps people who understand the properties of the low-level radio transmitters you are using can help? Alas, I don't think this site has the right people for you.

Comment: @NeilSmithline: Aha - I incorrectly read this as WiFi - thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @Neil Smithline  How does the repeater know when to update the packets or how many times they should be sent out repeatedly? The setting is not clear; are we using packets in the traditional OSi setup? If there is no authentication then the repeater would send out anything that looks like a packet. Better yet, if it has no means of tracking packets it is also vulnerable to replay attacks.

Comment: I agree. I believe that the problem can't really be answered in terms of "packets" or "network connections". The answer seems to require discussion of "signal strength" and "radio response delays".

Comment: If the communications are one-way, and you assume that the recipient's clocks may not be precisely synchronized with the transmitter's, then I don't think there's any way you can prevent the recipient from accepting transmissions that have gone through a blind repeater. If the communications are two-way, then you could establish a response delay timeout - that is, if an endpoint sends a request, and the response comes slower than expected, then the endpoint assumes the response has passed through a relay.

Comment: However, this is likely far from fool-proof and probably not very fault-tolerant. In short, I don't really think there's a practical way to do what you want - at least not using "normal" computer-based security measures.

Comment: @Kar: Related Wiki entries: 1. One name for this is [Relay Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay_attack) 2. [GPS has been successfully replay/relay attacked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_attack#GPS_Spoofing)

Answer (score 3):

The classical situation for radio-frequency repeaters threats concerns all radio-based identification/authentication systems (RFID cards, etc.), the goal being to establish a tunnel between the actual card located at a distant place and the authentication mechanism (a door lock for instance).

In such case, the goal is not to exactly to use timing (such authentication token just have no clock at all!), but to establish a challenge between the two involved parties and evaluate the latency by measuring the time needed for this challenge. If both parties are in a short range as expected, the latency should never go over some threshold, while if they are out-of-range with some relay retransmitting the signal, the latency may go over this range.

However, this solution is valid only if there is some protocolary communication between the involved parties, and if the considered threat involves a minimum distance between them to induce detectable latency.

The other solution becomes completely implementation dependant, and consists in trying to detect anomalies:

- Assume that each satellite, sensors or whatever bears a unique ID. The fact that the unexpected signal from F is received while A, B and C are also received may be detected and considered as an abnormal situation. This would require some mapping, some memory of the previous signal encountered while in learning mode, or some other special disposition which allow to deduce this anomaly using some algorithm if the ID can be disposed in a way matching some law (ID would merely be actual coordinates for instance).
- Following the same principle, if the robot is constantly listening radio information, signal strength may also be used to detect any brutal change in the signal strength of some sensor while the signal of the other sensors remains unchanged: this would clearly indicate an issue.
- Or something else, in your description the sensors communicate with the robot. Why not also include sensor-to-sensors communication in your scheme? The presence of repeater in such a network would inevitably create new connection nodes in your network, thus raising an alert.

These are a few ideas which came to my mind. However, as stated in the different comments, there does not seem to be any well-known standard at this level, so unlike what is recommended in usual cryptography you will most probably have to "roll your own" here in a way or another.